# Online/Offline mode synchronization issue

Tags: c++, mysql, database

I have coded a desktop manager software which add/remove and update some info on a HTTP server, the remote application is a website so the software communicate with an API that i create, this software communicate with the HTTP server in a live mode.

Recently i want to include an offline mode, the user will download info and the change will be saved somewhere in the pc once he is live, the synchronization between the offline user info and the live one will be made, but I'm stuck in how i can implement this feature, currently the API pattern is like this:

Software -> generate XML request -> HTTP server -> generate XML response -> software

And the amount of requests & responses in for example a 5 minute session is huge

I have an approach which consist on downloading the data and creating a SQLite document, then the user will update infos on the SQLite file once the user is online the software will send the SQlite file and do the merge with the primary MariaDB/MySQL on the server side ...

Who can help me here and share with me a simple approach yet effective to resolve this issue.

Thank you !